# Darknet make error: lot of undefined reference error with OpenCV library

Tags: opencv, makefile, compiler-errors, conda, darknet

I'm trying to **make** the [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#improvements-in-this-repository) ([My **Makefile**](https://github.com/newjoy2018/training/blob/master/Makefile)) on a computing cluster, with module *devel/cuda/10.2* and module *devel/cudnn/10.2* loaded.

```
Cuda Path: /opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/
CuDNN path: /opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cudnn/10.2/
OpenCV path: /home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/ (conda environment)
```

It occured a lot of undefined reference [**make** error(full version)](https://github.com/newjoy2018/training/blob/master/makeError):
part of them like following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --cflags opencv` -DGPU -I/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cudnn/10.2/include obj/image_opencv.o obj/http_stream.o obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/dark_cuda.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/darknet.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/captcha.o obj/route_layer.o obj/writing.o obj/box.o obj/nightmare.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/coco.o obj/dice.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/layer.o obj/compare.o obj/classifier.o obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o obj/rnn_vid.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/art.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/reorg_old_layer.o obj/super.o obj/voxel.o obj/tree.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/gaussian_yolo_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/conv_lstm_layer.o obj/scale_channels_layer.o obj/sam_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread `pkg-config --libs opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --libs opencv` -L/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/lib64/stubs -lcuda -L/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cudnn/10.2/lib64 -lcudnn -lstdc++

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.101, needed by /home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_hdf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by /home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjasper.so.4, needed by /home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_dict_set@LIBAVUTIL_56'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Dread'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling@PNG16_0'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Tarray_create2'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref@LIBAVCODEC_58'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG16_0'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Tset_size'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5P_CLS_DATASET_CREATE_ID_g'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_58'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
/home/kit/fast/zx7186/.conda/envs/yoloenv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_58'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Is this the problem of OpenCV? How could I fix it?
Thank you for your help.